# google maps multiple line segments

Tags: google-maps, line

this question is kind-of programming related but not exactly - see how we go...

I am trying to view a trip i have made using a gps tracking device onto google maps as one continuous line, however, when i upload the KML file onto google maps it is arbitrarily broken into about 7 different segments.

The trip was made in one go and when shown in google earth it is shown as one continuous line.

I have inspected the KML file and all coordinates are contained within the same single linestring element.

Does anyone know why this is occuring?

Regards
Grant.

Comment: Could you post a snippet of the KML? That'll be helpful in debugging. Thanks.

Comment: Hi anschauung, the file can be downloaded from the following link...
http://www.sendspace.com/file/as9rjd

thanks for your help.

Comment: You're talking about uploading it to 'My Maps', right?  I tried uploading it and it worked just fine.

Comment: the map is supposed to be one straight line from sydney to queenstown but it stops above queestown. when i look at the map details i can see it broken into about 7 segments and over 2 pages. do you not see that??? in MyMaps yes.

Comment: revise - this file is over 5 segments on one page - it is one line to queenstown but i want to make it one segment - not 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like other people have experienced the same problem that you're having, but I was unable to find a solution.  It seems that this is just a bug in the Google Maps KML parser.

If you don't mind creating your own map with the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/index.html), you should be able to [parse the file](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GGeoXml) with no problem.  There are also some sites like [this one](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/map_input) which will create a map from your KML file.

Comment: Hi chris, are you suggesting that making my own map with the API will not end up breaking the path into multiple segments? it seems like a lot of work, especially when i have a lot of maps that have the same problem..

Comment: Yeah, it would be a lot of work.  I was just unable to find a solution to the problem on maps.google.com.  You should register the bug with Google.  http://maps.google.com/support/bin/request.py?contact_type=open_bug